# Issue with form_load

Tags: c#, forms, load

I am trying to make certain labels buttons etc be visible on load up however, when I click off the form and back on to it the form_load code activates again.  Its as if it was an onClick event instead of load.

I am completely new to coding so this will probably be something extremely simple

Many Thanks

```
private void formCanvas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblUsed.Visible = false;
        lblScore.Visible = false;
        lblUsedLetters.Visible = false;
        lblGuessWord.Visible = false;
        lblUserChoice.Visible = false;
        lblWord.Visible = true;
        txtUserLetter.Visible = false;
        txtUserWord.Visible = true;
        btnSubmitWord.Visible = true;
        btnSubmitLetter.Visible = false;
        lblLives.Visible = false;
        btnExit.Visible = false;
        btnRestart.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the code on the constructor of the formCanvas class

```
public formCanvas()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblUsed.Visible = false;
    lblScore.Visible = false;
    lblUsedLetters.Visible = false;
    lblGuessWord.Visible = false;
    lblUserChoice.Visible = false;
    lblWord.Visible = true;
    txtUserLetter.Visible = false;
    txtUserWord.Visible = true;
    btnSubmitWord.Visible = true;
    btnSubmitLetter.Visible = false;
    lblLives.Visible = false;
    btnExit.Visible = false;
    btnRestart.Visible = false;

}
```

Comment: ah ok thanks a lot, is there a reason for it executing when I tab on and off the form though?

Comment: @Sifer Because depending on what you're referring to by "tabbing on and off" the form, the form may be reloading which in turn causes the OnLoad event to fire.